# Have the kernel load a user-defined function by default

Tags: functions, function-construction

I wrote a very simple function that I would like to act as if it were one of the default functions that came with *Mathematica*, so that you don't have to load or import any package before you make use of it.  The reason is, the function is so simple, that its almost just as easy to just re-write the function as it is to import a file every time.  It would be nice though if I just didn't have to do anything.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: $UserBaseDirectory <> "\\Kernel\\init.m" I usually put <<MyPackages` here.

Answer (score 4):

You could add it to the initialization file.
See more in the documentation:
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/file/init.m.html